# How to disable default context menu of QTableView in pyqt?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to **disable** a default context menu of QTableView in **pyqt**.

I have re-implemented the contextMenuEvent but it works on 1st time right click. When I click on the same Item 2nd time the default context menu **reappears**. (Image attached below for referance.)

I tried "**QTableView.setContextMenuPolicy(*Qt.NoContextMenu*)**" but it didn't work. Also referred the answers of similar type questions but still the issue is unresolved.

Any idea?

Ex. showing Re-implemented context menu in QTableView.

```
def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
    menu = QMenu(self)

    CutAction = QAction(self.view)
    CutAction.setText("&Cut")
    menu.addAction(CutAction)
    CutAction.setIcon(QIcon(":/{0}.png".format("Cut")))
    CutAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+X")
    self.connect(CutAction, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.cut)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the code that shows I can not reproduce your problem, even so the solution is to use `Qt::CustomContextMenu` by enabling the signal `customContextMenuRequested`, and in the corresponding slot you have to implement the logic:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class TableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TableView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.onCustomContextMenuRequested)

    def onCustomContextMenuRequested(self, pos):
        menu = QMenu()
        CutAction = menu.addAction("&Cut")
        menu.addAction(CutAction)
        CutAction.setIcon(QIcon(":/{0}.png".format("Cut")))
        CutAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+X")
        CutAction.triggered.connect(self.cut)
        menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(pos))

    def cut(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TableView()
    model = QStandardItemModel(10, 10, w)
    w.setModel(model)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.....I tried the above code but my custom context menu is disappeared and default menu is still there.

Comment: @String39 Have you tried my code or have you adapted it to your code?

Comment: I tried your code but default menu is still there. Also my custom context menu is disappeared.

Comment: @String39 What version of PyQt4 do you have?

Comment: I have installed PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.7-x32.

Comment: @String39 It smells like a bug, I've tried it many times and I have not had any problems, maybe updating it to PyQt4 4.12.1 be solved :)

Comment: ohh!!! You mean the custom menu shown in Fig.2 will be disabled on updating PyQt4 4.11.4 to PyQt4 4.12.1. I will update it. Thanks for your efforts.